# Spark MariaDB jdbc SQL query returns column names instead of column values

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, databricks

I'm running Apache Spark in Databricks, retrieving data from MariaDB. I have IoT files containing a device UUID, and I need to retrieve other information about the users to do an analysis. However, if I run the SQL query 'normally' against the database I get the data I expect, but when I run it from Spark I get something quite different.

```
query = """SELECT
        d.uuid,
        ch.gender AS sex,
        ch.cpp,
        ch.young_carer,
        ch.spp,
        ch.asylum_refugee
    FROM
        devices d
    LEFT JOIN device_sessions ds ON ds.device_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN children AS ch ON ds.person_id = ch.id"""
    
devices = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbcUrl).option("query", query).option("user", connectionProperties["user"]).option("useSSL", connectionProperties["useSSL"]).option("driver", connectionProperties["driver"]).option("serverSslCert", connectionProperties["serverSslCert"]).option("trustServerCertificate", connectionProperties["trustServerCertificate"]).option("password", jdbcPassword).load()
devices.show(10)
```

When I run it is Spark as above, I get

```
+----+---+----+-----------+----+--------------+
|uuid|sex| cpp|young_carer| spp|asylum_refugee|
+----+---+----+-----------+----+--------------+
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
|uuid|sex|true|       true|true|          true|
+----+---+----+-----------+----+--------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

If I query the database using this exact outside of spark,

```
SELECT
        d.uuid,
        ch.gender AS sex,
        ch.cpp,
        ch.young_carer,
        ch.spp,
        ch.asylum_refugee
    FROM
        devices d
    LEFT JOIN device_sessions ds ON ds.device_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN children AS ch ON ds.person_id = ch.id

|uuid|sex| cpp|young_carer| spp|asylum_refugee|  
|0002deff-64ef-47b8-a538-14ac4b824e2f |F |0|    0|  0|  0|
|000d63b1-d4e3-454e-865e-08fb24a14d0e |M |0|    0|  0|  0|
```

I'm expecting the same result in Spark. In these two rows all the values are present. Perhaps the problem is that some of the rows other than UUID have nulls? Or that I need to specify a schema for the types?

'children.gender' is varchar(255). The other 'children' columns are tinyint(1) = 0.
'devices.uuid' is varchar(255).
The join ids are all bigint(20). (however, I'm not able to retrieve any bigint(20) values, as I get a 'long is out of range' error, so I avoid that in the query.

This is making no sense to me. why the result is so different when run in different contexts. If anybody has a clue, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Simplifying further, I just take two columns, in case the nulls were confusing the other columns.

```
query = """SELECT
        d.`uuid`,
        ch.`gender`
    FROM
        devices d
    LEFT JOIN device_sessions ds ON ds.`device_id` = d.`id`
    LEFT JOIN children AS ch ON ds.`person_id` = ch.`id`"""
```

and I get

```
+----+------+
|uuid|gender|
+----+------+
|uuid|gender|
|uuid|gender|
|uuid|gender|
|uuid|gender|
|uuid|gender|
+----+------+
```

I found a similar question with someone using pyspark and Hive, but there were no answers to that one either.

Comment: Did you verify Datatypes of Join Columns

Comment: Simplifying further, I just take the uuid and gender columns only.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I did not show the url and other connection details in the question because of privacy concerns, but actually that is where the problem lies. The URL set up for this started 'jdbc:mariadb' but Spark doesn't recognise this. It need to be 'jdbc:mysql' even though it is a mariadb driver. Once that was changed the values came in as expected.

```
jdbcHostname = "hostname.mariadb.database.azure.com"
jdbcDatabase = "database_name"
jdbcPort = 3306
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
jdbcPassword = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "iot-blob", key = "password")
connectionProperties = {
  # verbose ssl properties are all required
  "useSSL" : "true",
  "trustServerCertificate" : "true",
  "serverSslCert" : "/FileStore/azure_mariadb_ca.pem",
  #I had to install the mariaDB driver to get a connection to work
  "driver" : "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
  #Credentials live here with pw passed in through databricks scopes
  "user"   : "username@host",
  "password" : jdbcPassword
}

result = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbcUrl) \
                  .option("query", query) \
                  .option("user", connectionProperties["user"]) \
                  .option("useSSL", connectionProperties["useSSL"]) \
                  .option("driver", connectionProperties["driver"]) \
                  .option("serverSslCert", connectionProperties["serverSslCert"]) \
                  .option("trustServerCertificate", connectionProperties["trustServerCertificate"]) \
                  .option("password", jdbcPassword).load()
```

Comment: Did you change it in the option 'url' only or you've changed it in the 'driver' too? By driver I mean something like this `option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")`

Comment: Would you mind adding the final version of your code to the answer? Because at the moment it lacks a lot of potentially helpful information.