# PySpark cannot decode value as Integer from mariaDb table

Tags: python, java, mysql, apache-spark, mariadb

I have this class

```
class SparkManager:
def __init__(self):
    self.conf = SparkConf()  # create the configuration
    self.conf.set("spark.jars",
                  "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.3.1/mariadb-java-client-3.0.6.jar")  # set the spark.jars

    self.spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .config(conf=self.conf) \
        .master("local") \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
        .getOrCreate()

def read_cards(self):
    dataframe_mysql = self.spark.read.format("jdbc")\
        .option('url', "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/xxxxx?user=xxxx&password=xxxx")\
        .option('dbtable', "(SELECT * FROM test) tmp")\
        .option('driver', 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver')\
        .load()

    dataframe_mysql.printSchema()

    dataframe_mysql.show()
```

and I run the instance of this object in main function

```
from sparkmanager import SparkManager


def main():
    spark_manager = SparkManager()
    spark_manager.read_cards()
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but when i run it i get the error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o34.showString. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to
> stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent
> failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (NB01GG003 executor
> driver): java.sql.SQLDataException: value 'c1' cannot be decoded as
> Integer   at
> org.mariadb.jdbc.plugin.codec.IntCodec.decodeTextInt(IntCodec.java:127)
> at
> org.mariadb.jdbc.codec.TextRowDecoder.decodeInt(TextRowDecoder.java:42)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.codec.RowDecoder.getIntValue(RowDecoder.java:145)

I checked my database tables. And the structure of db and tables is correct.
To my mind, the issue in mariaDb driver that it tries to parse string values in double but it gets double values. I tried to get values through pymysql and it fetches all the records correctly with proper types and values.

the schema shows right

```
root
 |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- c3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c4: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67160226/9250935 .

According to https://kontext.tech/article/1061/pyspark-read-data-from-mariadb-database :

- The DSN scheme should be changed to `jdbc:mysql://`
- The `permitMysqlScheme` parameter should be added to the URL

Something like `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxx?user=xxxx&password=xxxx&permitMysqlScheme"` should work in your case.